# Max-height transition is only working in one direction

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'm trying to implement a FAQ - therefore I want the answer to slide down on click. To achieve this effect I use `max-height`. But somehow **the transition solely works closing the question again.** On first reveal, there's no transition.

```
<div class="row mt-5">
  <div class="col-12" *ngFor="let question of questions; let i = index" (click)="selectedQuestion !== i ? selectedQuestion = i : selectedQuestion = -1">
    <div class="question-container py-4 h-100 w-100 border-bottom">
      <p class="mr-4">0{{i + 1}}</p>
      <p>{{question}}</p>
      <div class="answer-container" [class.answer-closed]="selectedQuestion !== i">
        <p>This is an answer!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 500px;
  transition: max-height .5s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
}

.answer-closed {
  max-height: 0;
}
```

A working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ir3a4n).

Comment: Please replicate what you have so far (HTML and CSS with dummy content) in the code-fiddle sandbox (Ctrl + M to open it while editing the question).

Comment: Also, not really required but would be great if you could also replicate the same in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) too.

Comment: @AndrewL64 Thanks, I've included a working stackblitz.

Comment: I would read the following might help you understand why your max-height approach isn't working how you want: https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your 'start' and 'end' value is always a number and not empty/null/something_else.